# All Possible Combinations String - Speed

Tags: jquery, for-loop, combinations

I've created a jquery script that generates all possible combinations of a string, where numbers and lower case letters are involved. I only want strings 10 characters long, so I threw in an if statement controlling that.

For those interested, here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var parts = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'];
    var url = "";

for (var a = 0; a < parts.length; a++) {
    for (var b = 0; b < parts.length; b++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < parts.length; c++) {
            for (var d = c + 1; d < parts.length; d++) {
                for (var e = d + 1; e < parts.length; e++) {
                    for (var f = e + 1; f < parts.length; f++) {
                        for (var g = f + 1; g < parts.length; g++) {
                            for (var h = g + 1; h < parts.length; h++) {
                                for (var i = h + 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                                    for (var j = i + 1; j < parts.length; j++) {
                                            url = parts[a]+parts[b]+parts[c]+parts[d]+parts[e]+parts[f]+parts[g]+parts[h]+parts[i]+parts[j];
                                            if (url.length === 10) {
                                                $("#URLs").append(url+', ');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

});
```

There's a for loop per character spot. If you just want strings 3 char's long, use only 3 nested for's.

It may be inelegant, but it works. My issue is speed/crashes.

Naturally, trying to run this through a browser is a bad idea. What would be a better program/language/set up for speed? I understand that I'm probably bound by my CPU's capabilities no matter what, and that brute forcing is always slow.

If there's a service that does this same thing, I guess that would work too.

Comment: Why do you need to use javascript to do this?

Comment: For these types of problems, usually recursion is a better solution than 10 for loops.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this? My only thought is that this is just the wrong way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I support Chris's question, and also want to ask - why do you need to generate all these strings at all?

Comment: To quote from the Question: `What would be a better program/language/set up for speed?`

Comment: To whoever is asking "Why do you need to do this?" I can understand being curious, but your questions don't seem to be genuine curiousity... Jason obviously has some sort of reason, so why does it matter? Maybe it's part of a game? Who knows?

Comment: @Greg Pettit I ask why because this is clearly not the right way to reach his end goal. By learning the true reasoning behind this code monstrosity, we can educate and possibly help this poor soul.

Comment: At least it may win the _Inception Code of the Year Award_

Comment: +1 for Greg's comment, "You don't really need this" is totally a MacForum Apple High and Mighty response to a question, he asks What would be a better language? So don't ask Why do you need JS to do this? He asks is there a better way to do this? Instead of slamming his solution provide one, jesus get off your high apple iHorses

Comment: @SSHThis Wtf are you talking about apple? To answer there is no better language for this. If hes looking for speed I would suggest Assembly.

Comment: You're much better off with recursion and some sort of lazy evaluation for this. You're looking at a silly amount of permutations for 10 characters in a 34 character population.

Answer (score 5):

You're not going to have a place to store the output.  You're talking about 3.656e+15 combinations, so your approach of appending that to a DOM element is not going to work.

Even if you used C/C++ or Java, you're still talking about something that's probably infeasible for your storage capacity.  And it would take way to long to submit that many requests if you just dynamically submitted them (vs. storing them).  I don't think you'll be successful with whatever (shady?) thing you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: To those who would down-vote my answer, please indicate why.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating 3656158440062976 strings, at 1 million strings per second your script would run for 115 years, at 1 billion strings per second it would be 42 days. And the resulting string (your `$('#URLs').append`) would be 36 petabytes at 1 byte per character.

I vote not feasible

```
(Math.pow(36,10)/1000000)/(60*60*24*365)
=115.93602359408219
(Math.pow(36,10)/1000000000)/(60*60*24)
=42.31664861184
(Math.pow(36,10)*10)/(1000*1000*1000*1000*1000)
=36.56158440062976
```

See [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=alpha+numeric+password&f1=10+characters&x=8&y=5&f=PasswordSingleAdvanced.pl_10+characters)

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this, as I believe this is your end goal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking

Answer (score 0):

Not to say I'm fully answering your question (there are still performance and memory limitations due to a huge number of permutations), but here's one of the algorithms which crossed my mind: treat the string as a big number in base N, where N is the number of allowed characters.

1. Start with string aaaaa..aa
2. If the character at the last position doesn't equal `0` (the last, "biggest" allowed symbol), increment it. Otherwise, set the character to `a` and increment the previous symbol if it's not equal to `0`. Otherwise, ... you get the point.
3. Repeat step 2 required number of times.

A good thing about this algorithm is that you can wrap it up in a function like `getNextString()` and call it needed amount of times.
Also, there's no recursion, so it should be faster in most languages.

Answer (score 0):

*What would be a better program/language/set up for speed?*

C/C++ would be good language. And use recursion.